# How is it possible to get a score of 2 billion in Cut the Rope?

Tags: cut-the-rope

I just played through the first box (cardboard) in Cut the Rope, aiming for the fastest times and therefore highest score. It seems like the absolute highest score you can get for a level is around 6,000 (I got just over 5,900 for essentially an 'instant solve').

So when I'd finished I amassed 139,800 points (avg ~5,600 per level). Imagine my surprise when I logged onto the game center only to find the top score for Cardboard Box is 2,298,946,210!!!

As far as I can tell, it only takes the highest score for each level, so playing through levels again doesn't keep adding to your score. Are all these users cheating in some way? Or is there another way to improve scores?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I'm nearly certain they're cheating. Generally, you'll find the value 2,147,483,647 as a high score, because this is the highest value <s>kids</s> people can input using their cheat programs. (highest value a `signed int` can store)

Comment: This sounds most logical. I just saw a few forum posts where others suggest the Game Center is full of cheaters.

Comment: Game Center and Plus+ are easy to hack from what I've heard - OpenFeint is a little more secure.

Comment: If 2,147,483,647 is the highest possible integer, it seems a bit odd that 2,298,946,210 would be the top score. It's still more than likely a hacked score.